# AS3 What's wrong with this code?

Tags: actionscript-3

Most of this is working and even with the error, it continues to work in part:

```
// Make PostItNote MC draggable and keep ON TOP
mcMXredBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

var q:int = 1;

// Add multiple copies of PostItNote when used
function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.parent.startDrag();
    event.currentTarget.parent.parent.setChildIndex(DisplayObject(event.currentTarget.parent),87);
    var my_PIN = new postItNote();
    my_PIN.name = "my_RTC" + q; // Doesn;t like this line
    this.parent.addChild(my_PIN);
    trace("my_PIN = " + my_PIN);
    this.my_PIN[q].x = 1388.05; // Doesn't like this line
    this.my_PIN[q].y = 100;
    q++;
}
```

The error is

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at postItNote/fl_ClickToDrag()[postItNote::frame1:71]"
```

Comment: you might need to provide more info than that. Where is this.my_PIN declared? is it an array? (you're accessing it as one). Is there a name public property in postItNode? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my_PIN.name = "my_RTC" + q; // Doesn;t like this line

This means that `name` is not a property of the `postItNote` class.

> this.my_PIN[q].x = 1388.05; // Doesn't like this line

You seem to be using the wrong syntax here. What you want is probably just:

```
my_PIN.x = 1388.05; // In this context, my_PIN already refers to the movie clip named '"my_RTC" + q'
```

Comment: Changing the syntax was right, I had left overs from other code! Must be tired. Thanks. Also, it was correct about just using my_PIN.x, I was confusing myself with brackets. Thanks again!